# Placing a mapmarker by klick results in setting the marker on acorner of the map-window

Tags: python, kivy, mapview

I want to set markers on the map by clicking on it. When I click a marker is set. However, the marker is placed on the left lower corner of the map. What am I doing wrong?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapMarker


Builder.load_string(
'''
#:import MapView kivy_garden.mapview.MapView
#:import MapMarker kivy_garden.mapview.MapMarker

<SimpleRec>
    name: "simple_rec"

    MDBoxLayout:

        MapView:
            id: smap
            lat: 48
            lon: 7.82
            zoom: 11
            on_touch_down: root.on_map_touch_down(self, *args)
'''
)


class SimpleRec(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_map_touch_down(self, touch, *args):
        lat, lon = self.ids.smap.get_latlon_at(*touch.pos)
        print(str(lat) + " " + str(lon))
        marker = MapMarker(lat=lat, lon=lon)
        self.ids.smap.add_marker(marker)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        simple_rec = SimpleRec(name='simple_rec')
        screen_manager.add_widget(simple_rec)
        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Surprisingly, when I extracted the necessary snippets out of my code the position where the markers are set changed from upper left to lower left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the arguments to your `on_map_touch_down()` method. To correct that problem, change:

```
on_touch_down: root.on_map_touch_down(self, *args)
```

to:

```
on_touch_down: root.on_map_touch_down(*args)
```

The `self` arg is not needed as it is automatically included in the `args`.

Then the method itself can be defined as:

```
def on_map_touch_down(self, mapview, touch):
```